# I want to get more results from youtube Data api or youtube search results

Tags: web-scraping, youtube-data-api, google-search, youtube-channels

Hello i am trying to scrap search results from youtube like channel usernames or channel ids.
I tried using Youtube Data api and even did not crossed thousand. I tried keyword travel

`
request = youtube.search().list(

```
q=keyword,

type='channel',

part='id',

maxResults=50  # Adjust this based on your needs, maximum is 50`
```

in json result i see
`    {
'kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse',

```
 'etag': 'yfBPaJGKNXfioCSMoT6xiCzESUk',
 'nextPageToken': 'CDIQAA',
 'regionCode': 'PK',
 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 25856, 'resultsPerPage': 50} 
 }
```

`

where i see total results are in thousands. I tried going to next page with nextPageToken and after some hundred results it stoped and this totalResults is different on every page. I was only able to get 500 channels id in file.

I tried using selenium to scrap but was only able to scrap 600-700 channels. I tried google search results
and was only to scrap few hundreds.
How to acheive my scraping goal of thousands. If i can do it using api it is be better but if there is any other solution can you please exaplain how to solve this issue.